# Issue with download multiple file with names in BASH

Tags: shell, file, download, xargs

I'm trying to download multiple files in parallel using xargs. Things worked so well if I only download the file without given name. `echo ${links[@]} | xargs -P 8 -n 1 wget`. Is there any way that allow me to download with filename like `wget -O [filename] [URL]` but in parallel?
Below is my work. Thank you.

```
links=(
    "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1901/sombrero_spitzer_3000.jpg"
    "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1901/orionred_WISEantonucci_1824.jpg"
    "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1901/20190102UltimaThule-pr.png"
    "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1901/UT-blink_3d_a.gif"
    "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/1901/Jan3yutu2CNSA.jpg"
)

names=(
    "file1.jpg"
    "file2.jpg"
    "file3.jpg"
    "file4.jpg"
    "file5.jpg"
) 

echo ${links[@]} ${names[@]} | xargs -P 8 -n 1 wget
```

Comment: I would write a wrapper script to `wget` that takes 2 arguments, `"$1"` (filename) and `"$2"` (url). Not quite sure how you pass 2 words to `xargs` at at time, but searching or reading `man xargs` or other resources should show you how to do it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel wget -O {2} {1} ::: "${links[@]}" :::+ "${names[@]}"
```

If a download fails, GNU Parallel can also retry commands with `--retry 3`.